# How to capture and verify Web application Page size in Truclient 12.60?

Tags: performance-testing, vugen, truclient

I am Working on truclient to measure Download Time of Text File.

Scenario :

1. Navigate to Link.
2. Provide valid creds and click login.
3. Text File opens in browser itself.

I want to verify the download size (page size) of step 3. I tried using verify options in Truclient, but it just checks for objects.

Is there a way to verify size of the web page? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make sure by sc-bytes (server to client bytes) and time-taken are both tracked in the web logs.

If your test environment is integrated with your log analysis solution (splunk, elk, sumologic, etc...), then you can just create a dashboard which shows all of the stats on your text file downloads in bytes and time from the server logs.